# PHP. Нужно без CMS на чистом php наложить русский текст на изображение по координатам

Tags: php, изображения, текст, gd

Требуется наложить Русский(кириллический) текст на изображение на чистом PHP(без CMS и фреймворков). В общем то у меня получается с английским текстом, но вот русский с иероглифами.
Копался с локалью, разные варианты пробовал не помогло.
Можно ли как то решить проблему, и вообще возможно ли это? Сервер выделенный на Centos 7, сейчас стоит php-gd если есть вариант пусть и с установкой дополнительных библиотек - такой тоже в данной задаче устроит, при этом разумеется лучше если есть возможность решить стандартными средствами и расширениями(вроде gd) PHP.

Comment: приведите пример кода с наложением текста

Answer (score 6):

Вывести русский текст на изображении в PHP используя только php-gd можно и при этом в настройках локали не требуется ничего менять(хотя про локаль моё предположение и метод про который я рассказываю действительно не связан с настройками локали, может ли локаль повлиять на вывод русского текста при использовании других функций php я интересовался вопросом, но однозначного ответа так и не получил, если кто в комментариях ответит мне бы было интересно).

Так вот, вам нужно использовать функцию ImageTTFtext и ещё обязательно шрифт который Вы будите использовать и укажите в этой функции обязательно нужно разместить на сервере, я размещал в той же папке что и php скрипт. То есть используете Arial - скачиваете ещё ttf шрифт(то есть файл arial.ttf) и его помещаете в папку с скриптом.

Рабочий пример использования PHP функции ImageTTFtext для размещения русского текста на изображении по ссылке http://blog.ivru.net/?id=189

Comment: Для ImageTTFtext локаль менять не надо. Но есть один момент! Для корректной её работы текст должен быть в кодировке UTF-8. Ежели ваш текст (русский) в другой кодировке, то его нужно перевести из вашей кодировки в UTF-8 и потом передать в функцию. И шрифт должен быть с UTF-8 раскладкой (а не какой-нибудь легаси) и содержать все печатные символы, которые входят в текст.

Comment: Да! Важное замечание. Теоретически сервер может работать и с Windows-1251 вот только функции текст(его биты) обязательно нужно передать в кодировке UTF-8.